# How to Get values inside Arrow function

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

How to Get values inside `Arrow function`, which is Inside an Object.

I want to access other properties of that Object.

```js
let obj = {
  name:'Ashu',
  age:123,
  show: ()=>{
    // I want to print Name and Age how to do that
    // Is there any other way to do get Name and Age Property
    // I don't want to replace the Arrow function
      console.log(obj.name, obj.age);
  }
}
obj.show()
```

Comment: you cannot use `this`. you also cannot `.bind()` arrow functions

Comment: *"Is there any other way to do get Name and Age Property. I don't want to replace the Arrow function"* If you don't want to replace the arrow function then there is no other way.

Comment: @FelixKling, Great Cool. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```js
let obj = {
    name: 'Ashu',
    age: 123,
    show: () => {
        console.log(obj.name, obj.age);
    }
}

obj.show();
```

Comment: Sure It would work, But is there any other way to do that, not using any Function also.

Comment: I don't think so, to print out the ```name``` and ```age```, you will need to use ```console.log``` inside a function, since you cannot do so on its own, otherwise you can access the values outside the object like this: ```let obj = { name: 'Ashu', age: 123 } console.log(obj.name, obj.age)```

Comment: I Just trying out, what are another different approach would be apart from following Points. In Arrow Function.

1. Using call()/Apply()/Bind()
2. Using the Same Object inside the Functions.

Answer (score 2):

```js
class Obj {
  constructor(){
    this.name ='Ansh';
    this.age = 123;
    this.show = () => {
        console.log(this.name, this.age);
      }

  }
}

let obj = new Obj();
obj.show();
```

Comment: This is the new way.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions don't capture current `this`, for capturing `this` you need to write a regular function.

```js
let obj = {
    name:'Ashu',
    age:123,
    show: function() {
        console.log(this.name, this.age);
    }
};

obj.show();
```